# jQuery AJAX call from multiple input fields within the 1 script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on my first HTML form that performs an AJAX HTTP POST using jQuery. When a user makes a change to an input text field and tabs out of the field it triggers the AJAX script which in turn calls a PHP script which performs a database update.

I've got this working successfully for my first input field - I would now like to extend this to a 2nd, 3rd etc input fields but want to try and avoid having multiple scripts that perform very similar functions. I'm new to jQuery and AJAX so learning the syntax as I go.

Here's my input fields:

Manager





Phone

Here's my Javascript that is working on the storeManager input field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#storeManager").change(function(){
        var storeManager = $("#storeManager").val();
        $.post('editProject.php', { storeManager: storeManager, id: '1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F' }, function(data) {
            $("#managerRow").addClass("success");

        }).fail(function () {
            // no data available in this context
            $("#managerRow").addClass("danger");
            $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
        });
     }); 
});
</script>
```

I essentially need to branch and pass an additional POST parameter to the editProject.php script so it knows which database field to update, and then conditionally add a class to the appropriate row.

Everything I've tried breaks the script when I try and get it to branch or pass a parameter based on the input field that is being edited. I haven't been able to find any examples that show the correct syntax to have the one script that is called by different input fields - I'm presuming this is possible instead of having multiple versions of the same script acting on different fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for multiple fields. Just call the same function from different input fields. I just broke your code into two parts.
1. onChange function of each individual field, and
2. function call by passing the field parameters.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#storeManager").change(function(){ yourFunction(this) }):

$("#worker").change(function(){ yourFunction(this) }):

$("#someX").change(function(){ yourFunction(this) }):

yourFunction(field)
{
    var value = $(field).val();
    var inputId=field.id;
    $.post('editProject.php', { inputValue: value, id: inputId }, function(data) {
        $('#'+inputId+'Row').addClass("success"); // (this looks like: *#storeManagerRow* ) you can change your Row id's accordingly to make your work easier. Eg: for **#storeManager** make this id as **storeManagerRow**

    }).fail(function () {
        // no data available in this context
        $('#'+inputId+'Row').addClass("danger");
        $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using `:input` or a `class` that they all have

```
$(":input").on("change", function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    var idOfInput = $(this).attr("id");

    //your post to php function using the above variables

});
```

From this you could post the `id` of the input to your php script using the `idOfInput` variable which you could then on the php side use a `case switch` to do a different query depending on which `id` is sent to the php

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/s800j6ub/1/) showing how it works

Answer (score 0):

You just try to post a value. for example `type`. Which should contain some value for identify the ajax call.

**If it is for login, then add `type = 'login'. Then check the value of $_POST['type'] and write php according to it`**

sample.php

```
if(isset($_POST['type']))
{
    if($_POST['type'] == 'login')
    {
        //your code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this kind of code :

```
$("#storeManager, #Manager, #Phone").change(function(){
```